# linux + visual studio 2013 + visualgdb, undefined reference to 'dlopen'

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2013, visualgdb

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>
using namespace std;

bool LoadEESQuote()
{
    void* m_handle;
    m_handle = dlopen("libEESQuoteApi.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    LoadEESQuote();
    return 0;
}
```

it is said

> need `-ldl` to compile

, so I set:

```
project properties-Configuration Properties-NMake-Additional Options: -lrt -ldl
```

but I still get error.
Please help me

Comment: Please show your compile and link commands.

Comment: `-lrt -ldl` These are not options for nmake and should not be set there. Try setting linker options.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to n.m. 
VisualGDB Project Properties- Makefile settings -Additional linker inputs: -ldl
and it is worked out